# Doesn't "__str__()" work properly in "admin.py" for Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, function, django-admin, django-messages

For example, I define [__str__()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#str) in **`Person` model** as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    def __str__(self): # Here
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Then, I define **`Person` admin** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, the full name is displayed in the message and list in **"Change List" page**:

[image]

But, when I define `__str__()` in **`Person` admin** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def __str__(self): # Here
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Or, when I define `__str__()` then assign it to [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) in **`Person` admin** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__',) # Here

    def __str__(self): # Here
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

The full name is not displayed in the message and list in **"Change List" page**:

[image]

So, doesn't `__str__()` work properly in **`Person` admin**?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the [`display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#the-display-decorator) decorator, if you want to use model methods?

Comment: No. What's your point?

Comment: Documentation you linked says: _"There are four types of values that can be used in `list_display`. All but the simplest may use the `display()` decorator, which is used to customize how the field is presented"_ And the example for _"A string representing a model attribute or method (without any required arguments)"_ shows the method being decorated with `display`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not talking about display() decorator. I'm talking if str() doesn't work properly in `Person` admin or not.

Answer (score 0):

`list_display` will lookup field based on `model._meta`. All class has their own `__str__` method, includes your model class which is `Person`. So `list_display` will use `__str__` method provided by your model class, even you don't implement it in your model class, it will provide the default implementation of `__str__`. Hence `list_display` show like what you got. On the other hand, `list_display` default value is `("__str__",)` equal to what you do above. Here is other approach which might work

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('whatever',) # Here

    def whatever(self, obj): # Here
        return obj.first_name + " " + obj.last_name
```